# How to solve for $x$: $e^{-x/d}\cdot (1-e^{-x/a})$ value that will give a certain $y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have a simple equation for $h(x)$ as a multiplication of two exponentials:

- $f(x) = 1-e^{-x/a}$
- $g(x) = e^{-x/d}$
- $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$

I solved $h(x)$ for its maxima at an $x$-value of $m= a\cdot\ln((a+d)/a)$. Thus I have created a scaled version to a max of $y=1$:

- $i(x) = h(x)/h(m)$

This looks like this:

[image: Graph]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tagnzdeqes

I would like to now be able to solve the lowest $x$-value of $i(x)$ for a given $y$ between $0$ and $1$ (say $y=r$). Ie. I would like to be able to work out the lowest $x$-value that provides a $y$ of say $0.2$.

I have tried entering it in equation solvers as:

$r = e^{-x/d}\cdot (1-e^{-x/a}), \mathrm{solve\, for\,} x$

But I cannot get an answer from them. $d$ and $a$ are both real numbers $>0$. Is this solvable?

Comment: $d$ and $a$ are both real numbers that are greater than 0. Is that any help?

Comment: Thanks but I'm sorry I don't understand. I'm trying to solve for the $x$ value of $i(x)$ that gives an arbitrary $y$ output. Does this provide that? Can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but as I said the equation I fundamentally want solved is: $r = e^{−x/d}∗(1−e^{−x/a}), solve for x$

Comment: OK it is clear now...

Comment: I tried to solve this last equation, but I get $d=0$  and ($a=1$) which either means that the equation has no solution or I did something wrong...The idea is to expand the expression and equate the exponents but again this leads to $d=0$.

Comment: I altered the title to show the equation.

Comment: I worked the problem for the unscaled version of it.This means that my $r$ is $r \times h(m)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for very few cases, in general, this equation will no show analyical solutions and you will need some numerical method such as Newton (xhich means that you need a starting guess of $x$.

In all the following, I assume $a>0$ and $d>0$.

Considering that you look for the zero's of 
$$f(x)=e^{-\frac{x}{d}}\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{a}}\right) -r$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{-x \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{d}\right)} \left(-a
   e^{\frac{x}{a}}+a+d\right)}{a d}$$ 
$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{-x \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{d}\right)} \left(a^2
   e^{\frac{x}{a}}-(a+d)^2\right)}{a^2 d^2}$$
The derivative cancels at a point
$$x_*=a \log \left(\frac{a+d}{a}\right)$$ which is a maximum since
$$f''(x_*)=-\frac{\left(\frac{a+d}{a}\right)^{-\frac{a}{d}}}{a d} <0$$ So, to get solutions, we need that
$$f(x_*)=\frac{d \left(\frac{a+d}{a}\right)^{-\frac{a}{d}}}{a+d}-r >0$$ If this is the case, we could try to get *estimates* using a Taylor expansion around $x_*$; this would give
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+O((x-x_*)^3)$$ Solving the quadratic would give
$$x_\pm=x_* \pm  \sqrt{-2\frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$ If $x_-<0$, we should use $x_-=0$ since $f(0)=-r$.

Using these guesses, we could start using Newton method.

Let us try using your numbers $a=0.01$, $d=0.4$  and $r=0.2$. This gives $x_+\approx 0.115$. Now, Newton iterates for the upper solution.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.114912 \\
 1 & 0.408407 \\
 2 & 0.586326 \\
 3 & 0.639840 \\
 4 & 0.643756 \\
 5 & 0.643775
\end{array}
\right)$$ For the other one
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.00000000 \\
 1 & 0.00200000 \\
 2 & 0.00224236 \\
 3 & 0.00224552
\end{array}
\right)$$

If we are only concerned by the smallest root, making a Taylor series around $x=0$ would give
$$f(x)=-r+\frac{1}{a}x- \left(\frac{1}{2 a^2}+\frac{1}{a d}\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ and keeping the smallest root, the *estimate*
$$x \sim \frac{2 a d-\sqrt{4 a^2 d^2-8 a^2 d  (2 a+d)r}}{2 (2 a+d)}$$
For the worked example, this will give as starting guess $x_0=0.00227069$ and Newton would converge very quickly.

Instead of Taylor series, we could also use $[1,n]$ Padé approximants. The simplest would give
$$x_{(1)}=-\frac{2 a d r}{2 a r+d (r-2)}$$ which, for the worked example, would give $ \frac{2}{895}=0.00223464$ and probably one iteration would suffice.

Another thing which could be done is an expansion of  $(f(x)+r)$ as a long Taylor series and use series reversion to get
$$x=a r+\frac{a  (2 a+d)}{2 d}r^2+\frac{a (3 a+d) (3 a+2 d)}{6 d^2}r^3 +\frac{a  (2
   a+d) (4 a+d) (4 a+3 d)}{12 d^3}r^4+\frac{a (5 a+d) (5 a+2 d) (5 a+3 d) (5 a+4
   d)}{120 d^4} r^5+\frac{a  (2 a+d) (3 a+d) (6 a+d) (3 a+2 d) (6 a+5 d)}{60
   d^5}r^6+O\left(r^7\right)$$ which would give, as an *estimate*, $x=0.00224549$.

**Edit**

For the case where $a \ll d$, we could instead look for the zero of
$$g(x)=x+a \log \left(1-r e^{\frac{x}{d}}\right)$$ Using Taylor series built at $x=0$ would give
$$g(x)=a \log (1-r)+ \left(\frac{a r}{d (r-1)}+1\right)x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ from which an estimate
$$x_0=-\frac{a d (r-1) \log (1-r)}{a r+d (r-1)}$$ For the worked example, this gives $x_0=0.00224547$